# Ghostscript : ps to pdf - keep the orientation

Tags: pdf-generation, ghostscript, postscript

I have a .ps document with 2 pages.
The first page is portrait mode and the second is a landscape mode.

I use ghostscript 9.18 : 
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=./test.pdf test.ps

My PDF have a correct first page to portrait mode and my second page is also in portrait mode but it is cut, I lose content !!!!

How to make my second page stay in landscape mode?

Thanks

EDIT : 
I did the test with a single page in my .ps file in landscape mode and I have the same problem, the page is cut off.
Accuracy, my .ps file does not contain text, it's an image

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your input file its impossible to tell for certain, but if you read the Ghostscript documentation in VectorDevices.htm you will find the AutoRotatePages switch, you probably want to change that.

If that doesn't help then you're going to have to share the file.

Other than that, you are using an old version of Ghostscript and should upgrade.

Comment: I do not want to turn the pages, I want the second page to be in landscape mode as in the input file

Comment: I did read what you posted, so yes, I understood what you wanted. However you clearly didn't read the documentation I pointed you at. If you do then you will see that the **default** for that switch is /PageByPage, obviously if that's not what you want then you need to change it. ie RTFM!!

Comment: The AutoRotatePages works if the .ps contains text, but I forgot to specify but my .ps contains only images

Comment: Well then it can't be that. As I said before, if you don't post an example file to demonstrate the problem, then we're left with guesswork. I am unable to guess at any reason for your described problem, if you want more help I think you're going to have to come up with an example.